# ThePirateBay Lense Not Removing from Unity

Tags: unity, uninstall, ppa, lenses

I can't seem to remove this lense. I installed it using this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-scope-piratebay python-lxml
```

I tried removing it using this:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-scope-piratebay python-lxml
```

It looked like it all worked in the terminal, so I logged out, then back in, and the lense is still in the dash. How do I get rid of it?

EDIT: It should also be mentioned that I'm using 13.04

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you installed the **`unity-scope-piratebay`** and **`python-lxml`** packages, they also installed the `python-cssselect` and `unity-lens-torrents` packages.

After removing the `unity-scope-piratebay` and `python-lxml` packages, you will have this in the dash:

[image]

I think this is the **`unity-lens-torrents`** package.

So yo can try to remove that package with:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-torrents
```

Then logout and login to see the changes.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, that worked! Thanks, no more pointless lense!